# How can I switch to another tab in UITabBarController programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a UITableView and I want to switch to another tab upon clicking a cell in UITableView.

I have already tried that but it doesn't work

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

MainView *mainView = [[MainView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
mainView.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;  

 }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're loading a new copy of your MainView each time a row is selected. These new copies aren't displayed anywhere. You need to access the tab bar controller of your existing, displayed instance of your main view.  Perhaps this will work:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that mainView.tabBarController isn't nil?

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```